# remembering state of checkbox from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I currently have a simple checkbox that when clicked and unclicked it saves the state to the database. Can I have that state to be also be loaded/remembered when the page is refreshed? If the last state was checked, it appears checked after you refresh the page.

I don't want to use local storage. I would like to access the database directly.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("[name='checkboxtest']").change(function(){
    if( $("[name='checkboxtest']").prop('checked') ){checkboxstatus = '1';}
    else{checkboxstatus = '0';}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkbox.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        })
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>





<?php 
if($row['checkboxstatus'] == 1) { 
    echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' class='complete' checked='checked' name ='checkboxtest' value= '1'/></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td><input type = 'checkbox' class='incomplete' name ='checkboxtest' value= '0'/></td>";
}
?>
```

```html
<?php
$lock = $_POST['checkboxstatus'];

$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE table
           SET column = ?
           WHERE row = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ds', $lock, 'row');
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
?>
```

Comment: What you want can be done. What part of your code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `name` and `class` of the checkbox mixed up.

If you're accessing it in PHP via `$_POST['checkboxstatus']` you therefore need to make the `name` attribute `checkboxstatus`. You also have some unnecessary string concatenations and extra spaces around the `=` signs that I've removed here:

```
if($row['checkboxstatus'] == 1) { 
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='complete' checked='checked' name='checkboxtest' value='1'/></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='incomplete' name='checkboxtest' value='0'/></td>";
}
```

Also, you should be using bound parameters with mysqli. Your current query is open to SQL injection.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE table
           SET column = ?
           WHERE row = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ds', $lock, 'row');
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, especially the tip for SQL injection. I made the changes and it's working as it did before. I'm still trying to figure out how to have the checkbox state stay when the page is refreshed. If the checkbox in the database is set to 1, display the box as marked. If the checkbox is set to 0 in the database, display the box as unmarked.

Comment: Where does `$row['checkboxstatus']` come from? This should be from the database.

Comment: I added a require_once file that gets a value for "$row['checkboxstatus']". Appreciate the help. Slowly learning. Answer accepted.